# "'null' is not an object (evaluating 'apiData.original_release_date.split')";

Tags: javascript, titanium

I'm making an app that pulls from GiantBomb's API which will display a catalog of games depending on the query searched. I want this to display a picture of the game, the title, and the date it was added.

Basically the problem I am having is that the API displays the date the game was created in a very illogical way (e.g "1983-12-31 00:00:00") with the last characters always being 00:00:00. (which is totally redundant) I'm using `.split()` and `.join()` to remove and replace this with a blank string. While some of the results populate and I see the results,

I am greeted with this big error screen giving me this error which I cannot make any sort of sense with since all of the objects have dates and are being replaced accordingly:

`[ERROR] :  Script Error {
[ERROR] :      backtrace = "#0 () at :0";
[ERROR] :      line = 54;
[ERROR] :      message = "'null' is not an object (evaluating 'apiData.original_release_date.split')";
[ERROR] :      name = TypeError;
;
[ERROR] :  }`

This will also randomly halt the many other rows from populating for no apparent reason. All which have their own dates as well.

This is the global object...:

`var nameObject = {
    name : "",
    original_release_date : "",
    image : "",`

which is being populated by this loop

```
        var posts = json.results;


        //Looping through the posts via JSON/////////////////////////
        for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
            var apiData = json.results[i];
            nameObject.name = apiData.name;
            nameObject.original_release_date = apiData.original_release_date.split("00:00:00").join("");
            nameObject.image = apiData.image;
            console.log(nameObject.name);
            console.log(apiData.original_release_date);
```

I want to avoid ANY RegExp. Any ideas would be appreciated greatly. Thanks!

Comment: Bump! I really need to figure this out really soon. Much thanks appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Considering you always get value like `1983-12-31 00:00:00` at `apiData.original_release_date`.

To split you can use :

```
nameObject.original_release_date = apiData.original_release_date.split(" ")[0];
```

P.S : Also it would be better if you check first the format of data ( means if it comes properly as you expected ).

Comment: Alright, I've changed my split as you've posted it. It seems more efficient, however I'm still experiencing the error. Also, what exactly do you mean check the format of the data? Do you mean the API? As in JSON or XML? If so, I've already parsed it as JSON.

Comment: Also just another heads up, the code indeed does work. When I close the error, I see that the dates are still working.

Comment: I mean that date is always show in the format ( `1983-12-31 00:00:00` ) you provided. Like if somehow date comes like this format ( `2014-11-14T04:59:43.291Z` ) then it could be a issue.

Comment: also it would be helpful if you post your JSON response once ( `json.results` ? ).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem! So as I thought, this was entirely the API's fault. Some `original_release_date` values were actually blank therefore being `null`. I also noticed this with some of the images as well. My solution to this is basically slapping a bunch of conditionals in my `for` loop.

```
        //Looping through the posts via JSON/////////////////////////
        for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
            var apiData = json.results[i];
            nameObject.name = apiData.name;
            if (apiData.original_release_date != null) {
                nameObject.original_release_date = apiData.original_release_date.split(" ")[0];

            } else {

                nameObject.original_release_date = "";
            }
            if (apiData.image != null) {
                nameObject.img = apiData.image.super_url;
            } else {

                nameObject.img = "";
            }

            if (apiData.name != null) {
                nameObject.name = apiData.name;
            } else {

                nameObject.name = "(Unknown Game Name)";
            }`
```

If anyone has a more efficient solution, please let me know - thanks!